# Why can a compiler convert char to int in C++?

Tags: c++, char, int

Through programming in java and now in C++, I have found that you can convert a `char` to an `int` and then a `int` to a `double`.

I want to know why is that a `char` can be converted to an `int`?

In C++ they don't have the same amount of memory allocated to them, `char` is 8 bits and a `int` is 32 bits. So how does this work?

Is that just how the compiler is setup? I just want an explanation.

Thanks for any and all help!!

Comment: That's like asking how is it possible to pour 8 liters of water in a bucket that has a volume of 32 liters.

Comment: Are you asking why the language is defined that way, or where in the standard does it say it's OK to convert a `char` to an `int`?

Comment: Short answer: because standard allows that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some architectures, every value that a `char` can hold, an `int` can also hold. So if you have a `char`, you can use it to initialize an `int` by giving the `int` the same value that the `char` holds. This shouldn't be surprising.

On other architectures this isn't true. Still C++ allows any integer type to be converted to any other integer type. This must be true because it was allowed in C also, but you can prevent such "narrowing" conversions using brace-initialization.

What I think you're concerned about---which should be a concern on *any* architecture---is take a `char` and "pass it off" as an `int`. But that's not what converting `char` to `int` does. It *is* what converting to `int&` using `reinterpret_cast` would do; such a conversion is dangerous and potentially triggers undefined behaviour; not only because `int` and `char` don't have the same size, but also because they may not have the same representation even if they do have the same size.

Comment: Re "Every value that a char can hold, an int can also hold", nope. E.g., with `CHAR_BIT` = 16, 16-bit `int`, and unsigned `char`.

Comment: Oops, I forgot that `char` can be unsigned. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Promotion between numerical types is legitimate by the C++ standard. Meaning, this feature is part of the C++ language.

Specifically for the promotions you are referring, a `char` can be promoted to an `int` and an `int` can be promoted to a `double` without loss of precision because the standard guarantees that:

```
sizeof(char) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(double)
```

That is the range of values represented by `char` is surely included in the range of values represented by `int` and the range of values represented by `int` surely is included in the range of values supported by `double`.

Comment: "That is the range of values represented by char is surely included in the range of values represented by int", no, `char` can be unsigned. With the compilers I use that property can be chosen via a compiler option.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf isn't it `[0, 255] in [INT_MIN, INT_MAX]`?

Comment: The number of bits per `char` is given by `CHAR_BIT` from the `<limits.h>` header. It is greater or equal to 8. E.g. on some Texas Instruments DSPs it's 16.

Answer (score 0):

Frozen history. C++ was based on C, and still almost has C as a proper subset. And in the 1970s, when C was developed, there was no big difference between a *byte* and a *character*: almost all, if not absolutely all, the main text encodings used a single byte per character.

In modern C++ `char` and its two variants `unsigned char` and `signed char` is just the basic byte type, where a byte is defined as the smallest adressable unit of memory, and when used for characters `char` is just the basic encoding unit (e.g. with UTF-8 a *character* consists of one to five, I think it was, bytes).

Since and including with the standardization in 1998 C++ has acquired three more purposed character types: `wchar_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`, but unfortunately no *strongly typed* such type.

---

The compiler options or setup don't affect *whether* `char` converts implicitly to integer, but they affect whether plain `char` is a signed or unsigned type. Usually it's signed, also for historical reasons, which is impractical. As a signed type it's still distinct from `signed char`, e.g. with respect to overload resolution of a function call, and as an unsigned type it's distinct from `unsigned char`.

---

You can define a strongly typed byte size character encoding value type by using an `enum`:

```
using Byte = unsigned char;
enum class Byte_char : Byte  {};
```

“Strongly typed” means that it doesn't convert implicitly to number.

However, I prefer the more relaxed type checking of

```
enum Byte_char : Byte  {};
```

which converts *to* integer, but is a type distinct from uses of `Byte` for other purposes (this doesn't mean that I use a `Byte_char` type, it's just about what I find practical when defining such a type).

As far as size is concerned such a type can in practice also be defined as a `struct`, because as far as I know no extant C++ compiler inserts padding in a single byte `struct`. However, such a definition can be incompatible with the “short buffer optimization” of `std::basic_string`. The `enum` works fine with that optimization.

Answer (score -1):

`char` is not converted to `int`. The ASCII code of `char` is assigned for `int` value. If you convert the `char` '5' to `int`, you have to get integer value 5. But you will get 53 which is the code of '5'. The byte holding ASCII code is directly extended to 32 bit value.